# how to query database for modification of record

Tags: sql

Retired 15 years but was a database manager.  I have done a lot of queries for data and reports for hospitals.I would like to know if a large bank database  or backup can be queried to find if the record of a deposit I made was modified.  I have good reason to believe that it was.  I was thinking about a last modified date field but from what I remember most databases records do not contain a last modified date field.

Comment: Each database has different meta data. Which one are you using?

Comment: Couldn't you do a query that looks for that specific ID across old backups and see if the record is the same?  Or do you not have access to that old of backups when the change was suspected?

Comment: Also, I think this question could be better answered at dba.stackexchange.com. Stackoverflow is geared towards programming questions, not admin ones.

Comment: Of course a bank keeps track of all transaction. Required by law in most countries.